# How to display the data in table from selecting specific id to get multiple rows from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need to display the multiple rows in form for table ".table table-bordered" onclick for a specific id

My Query is working fine. but I don't know how to display the multiple data in different rows for the id.

So What I need

Onclick of the view button, the form modal will be displayed with `u_lead_number` in the input field and for the specific `lead_number`, I need the different product details in the table view, inside the same form.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-view-lead_creation" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-view-lead_creationTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1270px;" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-add-lead_creationTitle" align=center>View Lead Creation</h3>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel-body pan">
                    <form name="view_lead_creation-form" id="view_lead_creation-form" method="POST" action="lead_status_transfer_update.php" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-separated">
                        <h4>Lead Details:</h4>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-body pal">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">LEAD NUMBER <span class='require'>*</span></label>
                                        <div class="input-icon right">
                                            <input type="text" id="u_lead_number" name="u_lead_number" placeholder="Lead Number" class="form-control form-rounded" disabled/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="success text-center">Sl.no<span class='require'>*</span></th>
                                            <th class="success text-center">Product<span class='require'>*</span></th>
                                            <th class="success text-center">Price<span class='require'>*</span></th>
                                            <th class="success text-center">Delete</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="ulead_product" id="ulead_product"  class="datepicker-default form-control form-rounded"/></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="ulead_price" id="ulead_price"  class="datepicker-default form-control form-rounded"/></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="ulead_qty" id="ulead_qty"  class="datepicker-default form-control form-rounded"/></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="list_lead_creation_table" width="98%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th >SL NO</th>
            <th >LEAD NUMBER</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th ></th>
            <th >LEAD NUMBER</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php
              $query = "SELECT * FROM mgen_leadf_details";
              $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('error2');
              if(mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0){
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
            ?>
            <?php
              $lead_create_querys = "SELECT mgen_leadf_products.lead_product AS product,  mgen_leadf_products.lead_price AS price, mgen_leadf_products.lead_quantity AS quantity WHERE lead_num = '".$row['lead_num']."'";
              $create_datas = mysqli_query($conn, $lead_create_querys) or die('error5');
              if(mysqli_num_rows($create_datas) > 0){
                  while($lead_created_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($create_datas)){
            ?>
            <td>
                <button type="button" data-target="#modal-view-lead_creation" 
            onclick="set_ulead_creation_details('<?php echo $row['lead_num'];?>','<?php echo $lead_created_rows['product'];?>','<?php echo $lead_created_rows['price'];?>','<?php echo $lead_created_rows['quantity'];?>');" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary form-rounded"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>View</button>
            </td>
            <?php }
            }?>
            <?php }
            }?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
function set_ulead_creation_details(ulead_num_id, ulead_product, ulead_price,
    ulead_qty)
{
    $("#u_lead_number").val(ulead_num_id);
    $("#uproduct_id").val(ulead_product);
    $("#ulead_price").val(ulead_price);
    $("#ulead_qty").val(ulead_qty);
}
</script>
```

Example for how output i needed:
[image]

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: @Dharman Give any example sir.

Comment: `lead_num = '".$row['lead_num']."'` is vulnerable.

Comment: I don't agree. Although prepare statements is good practice, in this case this field is getting from other table not from user input, so it is not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you hava a SELECT N + 1 problem in your approach. Query should join products table to details table like that:

```
SELECT p.lead_num, p.lead_product AS product, p.lead_price AS price, p.lead_quantity AS quantity
FROM mgen_leadf_details d
         JOIN mgen_leadf_products p ON d.lead_num = p.lead_num
```

Then you have to iterate one level up than you do now:

```
<?php while($lead_created_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($create_datas)) : ?>
   <tr>
     <td>
            <button type="button" data-target="#modal-view-lead_creation" 
            onclick="set_ulead_creation_details('<?php echo $lead_created_rows['lead_num'];?>','<?php echo $lead_created_rows['product'];?>','<?php echo $lead_created_rows['price'];?>','<?php echo $lead_created_rows['quantity'];?>');" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary form-rounded"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>View</button>
        </td>
   </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Full code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-view-lead_creation" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-view-lead_creationTitle"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1270px;" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-add-lead_creationTitle" align=center>View Lead Creation</h3>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel-body pan">
                    <form name="view_lead_creation-form" id="view_lead_creation-form" method="POST"
                          action="lead_status_transfer_update.php" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                          class="form-separated">
                        <h4>Lead Details:</h4>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-body pal">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">LEAD NUMBER <span
                                                    class='require'>*</span></label>
                                        <div class="input-icon right">
                                            <input type="text" id="u_lead_number" name="u_lead_number"
                                                   placeholder="Lead Number" class="form-control form-rounded"
                                                   disabled/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="success text-center">Sl.no<span class='require'>*</span></th>
                                        <th class="success text-center">Product<span class='require'>*</span></th>
                                        <th class="success text-center">Price<span class='require'>*</span></th>
                                        <th class="success text-center">Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="ulead_product" id="ulead_product"
                                                   class="datepicker-default form-control form-rounded"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="ulead_price" id="ulead_price"
                                                   class="datepicker-default form-control form-rounded"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="ulead_qty" id="ulead_qty"
                                                   class="datepicker-default form-control form-rounded"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="list_lead_creation_table" width="98%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>SL NO</th>
        <th>LEAD NUMBER</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>LEAD NUMBER</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT p.lead_num, p.lead_product AS product, p.lead_price AS price, p.lead_quantity AS quantity
                        FROM mgen_leadf_details d
                        JOIN mgen_leadf_products p ON d.lead_num = p.lead_num";
        $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('error2');
        ?>
        <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) : ?>
            <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) : ?>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" data-target="#modal-view-lead_creation"
                            onclick="set_ulead_creation_details('<?php echo $row['lead_num']; ?>','<?php echo $row['product']; ?>','<?php echo $row['price']; ?>','<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>');"
                            data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary form-rounded"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>View
                    </button>
                </td>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    function set_ulead_creation_details(ulead_num_id, ulead_product, ulead_price, ulead_qty) {
        $("#u_lead_number").val(ulead_num_id);
        $("#uproduct_id").val(ulead_product);
        $("#ulead_price").val(ulead_price);
        $("#ulead_qty").val(ulead_qty);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Its not working as you suggest. Can you edit in my code for my clear understanding. Thanks

Comment: I add full code, test it and if it's still don't work, check in page source if `set_ulead_creation_details` function parameters is set.